# Adding 你, 你們, 您 after interjections

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

So I've noticed that for 謝謝 and 歡迎, it is common to put 你 or another 2nd person pronoun afterwards, though it's not required.

謝謝 vs 謝謝**妳**
歡迎到佛蒙特 vs 歡迎**你們**到佛蒙特

I'm assuming that because these expressions are interjections, they are fossilized to an extent.

My two questions are;

1. Is there any difference between adding or not adding 你? Like how in English 'thank you' is slightly more polite than 'thanks'. (I realize that adding 你們 instead of 你 would change the meaning, I just mean adding the second person pronoun in general.)
2. Are there other verbs/interjections that behave this way in Chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 你, 你們, 大家, and XXX (a person's name) are often inserted to intensify the welcomeness towards the person/group in focus.
2. I'll come back if I find one.